# How to make margins collapse evenly?

Tags: css, margins

I want my margins to collapse fully before the body starts to become narrower like how it is on http://www.skysports.com/, and only when the margins have fully collapsed then the body can become narrower. I've been playing around with px, em, and % in my css for ages and haven't been able to make it work. Here is what i have so far.

```
html { background-image:url(images/webBackground.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    height:100%; width:100%;
    }

body { background:black;
    height:100%; width:75%;
    margin:0 12.5% 0 12.5%;
    }

#container { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Try `auto` instead of `12.5%`.

Comment: what do you mean by `collapse fully before the body starts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nAcS4/) exmaple of what I think you're asking for.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="main-content">

        <div class="push"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;  
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px; /* specific resolution width */
  margin: 0px auto 0px;    
}

#main-content {
  background-color: red;   
}

#main-content .push {
  height: 500px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didnt fully understand your question. Assuming that you need your image center aligned  whatever width of the screen.

```
body
{background: url(images/webBackground.jpg) no-repeat fixed center 0 black;}
```